# How to pass request in forms.BooleanField to get the data from database in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using `forms.BooleanField` for checkbox filtering. I got stuck on getting the data from the database.

**Meaning:** If the user clicks on the `SAMSUNG` product the data should filter all the `SAMSUNG` products.

well, I have tried to get the brand list from the database and it is doing well but when I click on a specific brand it does not filter a specific brand. (*rather it just refresh and show the same data*)

*`Code goes here:`*

**forms.py**

```
class BrandForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        brands = Product.objects.filter(category=1).values_list('brand', flat=True)
        for brand in brands:
            self.fields[f'{brand}'] = forms.BooleanField(label=f'{brand}', required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def product(request):
    product = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    formBrand = BrandForm()
          
    return render(request, 'list/product.html', 
    {'product': product, 'formBrand':formBrand}
    )
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'main:product' %}" method="get">
            {{ formBrand.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
          </form>
```

**What all the code should be implemented?**

## Edit 1

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1330)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1330)
    image_src = models.URLField(max_length=1330,null=True, blank=True)
    link_href = models.URLField(max_length=1330,null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length = 1330, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: can you share the view for this  `main:productdata` ?

Comment: you can't get form data from GET request, change it to use POST method instead

Comment: hello @Arjun, it is only `main:product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you approaching the form a wrong way, firstly you need to have POST method to get data from form, then filter product based on selection from form and re render the page.

So the form should be:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:productdata' %}" method="POST">
            {{ formBrand.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
          </form>
```

And in your view:

```
def product(request):
    product = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formBrand = BrandForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formBrand = BrandForm(request.POST)
        if formBrand.is_valid():
           brand_names = []
           # get list of brand name as form name
           for brand_name in formBrand.cleaned_data:
              if formBrand.cleaned_data[brand_name] == True:
                 brand_names.append(brand_name)
           if brand_names:
              product = Product.objects.filter(brand__in=brand_names).order_by('-id')
          
    return render(request, 'list/product.html', 
    {'product': product, 'formBrand':formBrand}
    )
```

Comment: first, I run this code I get an error as `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`. after that i enter `<form...>{% csrf_token %}
            ...
          </form>` then it showing nothing

Comment: means after clicking `SAMSUNG` checkbox there is no o/p (blank page)

Comment: I have inserted my `models.py`

Comment: @santoshChauhan try printing out `formBrand.is_valid():` see if the form is valid, or to check if you sending the form to the correct route

Comment: `[25/Jun/2021 09:53:01] "POST /product/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5559` I'm getting this in vs code `terminal`

Comment: `path('product/', views.product, name='product'),` mine url

Comment: How I filter the brand from product: `brand = request.GET.get('brand')

        if brand:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=1).filter(brand=brand)
        else:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=1)`

Comment: no i mean add print(formBrand.is_valid()) before the `if formBrand.is_valid()`, after select a brand and click ok check in terminal what value does it printed out

Comment: it showing `true` `True
[25/Jun/2021 10:04:10] "POST /product/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5551`

Comment: @santoshChauhan so now we know that it's calling the view correctly,  now try printing out to check `formBrand.cleaned_data` what does it return?

Comment: Its printing `{'Samsung': True, 'LG': False}`

Comment: I checked for `brand_names`:. it printing `['Samsung']`

Comment: ok now print out product  before rendering, see if it's empty or not

Comment: which line sir?

Comment: I did this: `print(product)`. in the list line. then i got this `<QuerySet []>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234190/discussion-between-santosh-chauhan-and-linh-nguyen).